# Can you implement Vue Unit tests without a component using purely the Vue Instance?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-component

I briefly looked at the documentation on [Vue Unit Testing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html)

It said:

> Anything compatible with a module-based build system will work

The documentation describes ways to test components

In my case I am not using a component.
I am adding the `vue.js` to the page and I create a new Vue Instance.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ....
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Here is a simple example with **QUnit** where we test a "Hello, World!" message:

```js
QUnit.test('"Hello, World!" is displayed', function (assert) {
  assert.equal(vm.$data.message, 'Hello, World!');
  assert.equal(document.querySelector('h1').textContent, 'Hello, World!');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/2.4.0/qunit.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>

<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/2.4.0/qunit.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello, World!'
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this and see how it is. Is there no command line option?

Comment: If you go for QUnit, you do not really need a CLI because you can run tests in a browser environment (as you can see in my JSFiddle).

Comment: Hmmm, I feel that this might cause code duplication. As I will have the one js file with `qunit` and will have to copy to another `production` file